# rsync in cron without ssh-agent?

Tags: linux, ssh, backup, rsync, cron

I'm setting up backup server, that will connect to production server and fetch backup with rsync via cron task. I have user on my backup server, I created public key and I can log with ssh to production without typing password, but I need to add my key to ssh-agent.

```
ssh -p 1234 -i id_rsa_pass prod_user@production.com
```

The problem is that when I log out, ssh-agent is off and rsync fails, because it wants password.

```
rsync -azP --delete -e "ssh -p 1234 -i /home/backup_user/.ssh/id_rsa_pass"  prod_user@production.com:/home/prod_user/backup/  /home/backup_user/backup
```

Is it possible to use rsync in cron without password? When my key has password and it is not possible to add key to ssh-agent?

Is it good idea to use key without password?

Answer (score 0):

It is not (generally) advisable to have a private ssh key without a password, simply because if anyone can get that key file, they can then "impersonate" you on any system where you've installed the corresponding public key.

The only situation under which I would create a private key with **no** passphrase  would be to create a **separate** private key with no password and used a forced command in your `authorized_keys` file tied to that associated public key.

Here's a good answer with more details on how to do that:

https://serverfault.com/questions/749474/ssh-authorized-keys-command-option-multiple-commands